# Хранение объекта как набора полей и кастомные атрибуты в EFCore

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Здесь и далее используется EFCore и Postgresql

Этот вопрос может быть достаточно глупым, но
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сохранить объект в таблице в виде набора свойств
Пример для общего понимания:

```
Blog
{
 public Guid BlogId { get; set; }
 public Location LocationOfBlog { get; set; }
}
```

```
  public class Location  
{
        public int Latitude { get; set; }
        public int Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Я хотел бы получить следующую интерпретацию при создании миграции

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Blogs",
                columns: table => new
{
BlogId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
LocationOfBlog.Latitude = table.Column<int>(type: "integer",name:"LocationOfBlogLatitude ", nullable: false),
LocationOfBlog.Longitude = table.Column<int>(type: "integer",name:"LocationOfBlogLongitude", nullable: false),
}
```

Из того что нашел в интернете предлагают хранить такие значения либо в jsonb либо в отдельной таблице,
оба варианта кажутся  мне не самыми удобными, я не готов ради двух полей заводить море дополнительных ключей и ещё осуществлять лишний поиск

В довесок, у меня есть метод позволяющий к IMutableProperty добавить интерпретацию в виде Json

```
 internal static void AddJsonConversion(this IMutableProperty property)
        {
            Type propType = property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType;
            Type builderType = typeof(PropertyBuilder<>);
            Type createdType = builderType.MakeGenericType(propType);
            object proBuilder = Activator.CreateInstance(createdType, property);
            typeof(PropertyJsonConverter).GetMethod(nameof(AddJsonConversion))?.Invoke(proBuilder, null);
        }

        public static PropertyBuilder<T> AddJsonConversion<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> propertyBuilder)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            return HasJsonConversion(propertyBuilder);
        }

        public static PropertyBuilder<T> HasJsonConversion<T>(PropertyBuilder<T> propertyBuilder)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            ValueConverter<T, string> converter = new ValueConverter<T, string>
            (
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(v) ?? new T()
            );

            ValueComparer<T> comparer = new ValueComparer<T>
            (
                (l, r) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l) == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r),
                v => v == null ? 0 : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v).GetHashCode(),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v))
            );

            propertyBuilder.HasConversion(converter);
            propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueConverter(converter);
            propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
            propertyBuilder.HasColumnType("jsonb");

            return propertyBuilder;
        }
```

Я не готов использовать его следующим образом

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property(p => p.LocationOfBlog ).AddJsonConversion();
```

мне было бы куда приятнее использовать его в виде атрибутов, но я не нашел класса аннотации от которого можно было бы унаследоваться, соответственно попробовал написать свой парсер, но столкнулся с проблемой что EF разбивает объекты сущностей на подобъекты и соответственно данный метод вернет для

```
   public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
```

3 проперти, а именно: Latitude Longitude и BlogId, в то время как я хотел получить BlogId и Location

```
 public static IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> AllProperties(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder,
            Func<PropertyInfo, bool> filter = null)
        {
            return modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties()).Where(x => filter?.Invoke(x.PropertyInfo) ?? true);
        }
```

Вопрос: есть ли класс от которого можно унаследоваться чтобы аплаить настройки к пропертям или, как дописать парсер чтобы обойти такое разбиение сущности EF

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [Table Splitting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting).

При этом нужно в класс `Location` добавить свойство `Id`, которое будет иметь то же самое значение, что и в сущности `Blog`. Это единственное неудобство. Зато всё остальное очень просто.

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Location LocationOfBlog { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Latitude { get; set; }
    public int Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Указываем, что обе сущности мапятся на одну таблицу.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>(location =>
{
    location.ToTable("Blog");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(blog =>
{
    blog.ToTable("Blog");
    blog.HasOne(o => o.LocationOfBlog).WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Location>(location => location.Id);
});
```